# Rails dynamic select not working in Rails 5 (Railcasts #88)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement a dynamic select based on Railscasts #88 but to no avail. I have searched up and down but no success yet.

I have the `Staff`, `Question` and `Redesignation` models.

```
class Staff < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :redesignation
  belongs_to :question
end

class Question < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :redesignations
  has_many :staffs
end

class Redesignation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :staffs
  belongs_to :question
end
```

In the _form partial for creating a new staff, when one selects a question, redesignations will be populated accordingly.

```
<%= f.label :question_id,'Do you feel you are in the right designation?' %>
  <%= f.collection_select :question_id, Question.order(:name), :id, :name, 
include_blank: true %>

  <%= f.label :redesignation, 'Proposed Redesignation' %>
  <%= f.grouped_collection_select :redesignation_id, Question.order(:name), 
:redesignations, :name, :id, :redesignation, include_blank: true %>
```

Here is the jQuery in staffs.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#staff_redesignation_id').parent().hide()
  redesignations = $('#staff_redesignation_id').html()
  $('#staff_question_id').change ->
  question = $('#staff_question_id :selected').text()
  escaped_question = question.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, 
  '\\$1')
  options = $(redesignations).filter("optgroup[label='# 
{escaped_question}']").html()
if options
  $('#staff_redesignation_id').html(options)
  $('#staff_redesignation_id').parent().show()
else
  $('#staff_redesignation_id').empty()
  $('#staff_redesignation_id').parent().hide()
```

Despite my best efforts I have not seen the light. Any ideas of where I could be going wrong?

Edit: Here is the image of my indentation: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZubA.png)

Comment: It would be best to also show the HTML form generated by Rails

Comment: Define "not working"

Comment: The options in the second dropdown are not affected by the first selection

Comment: The html produced is `<label for="staff_question_id">Do you feel you are in the right designation?</label>
      <select name="staff[question_id]"><option value=""></option>
<option value="2">No</option>
<option value="1">Yes</option></select>

      <label for="staff_redesignation">Proposed Redesignation</label>
      <select name="staff[redesignation_id]"><option value=""></option>
<optgroup label="No"><option value="2">Senior Assistant Director</option></optgroup><optgroup label="Yes"><option value="1">Director, Clinical Services</option></optgroup></select>`

Comment: I am 99.99% confident that this is caused by the wrong indentation in coffeescript code.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of my indentation @Sergio Tulentsev     Thank you!

Comment: @adamvanbart: why is it broken here then? Are you mixing tabs and spaces?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev: My bad, I seem not to have paid much attention when formatting my question. But as you can see from the image, I don't think there is a problem with the formatting in my code.